# Проблема с импортированием функций из других файлов

Tags: python, импорт

Хочу собрать игру, но при компиляции происходит следующая ошибка

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Виктор/Desktop/py/Подземелья/main.py", line 3, in <module>
    from data.gamedb import p_exp
  File "C:\Users\Виктор\Desktop\py\Подземелья\data\gamedb.py", line 2, in <module>
    from main import player_name
  File "C:\Users\Виктор\Desktop\py\Подземелья\main.py", line 3, in <module>
    from data.gamedb import p_exp
ImportError: cannot import name 'p_exp' from 'data.gamedb' (C:\Users\Виктор\Desktop\py\Подземелья\data\gamedb.py)
```

Вот коды в самих файлах

**main.py**

```
from data.location import locale
from data.location import player_Home
from data.gamedb import p_exp

def user_print():
    print("Информация о персонаже:\nHP:" + str(p_exp.heals) + "\nИнвентарь:" + str(len(p_exp.enventory)))
print("Добро пожаловать в игру \"Подземелья\" ")

player_name = input("Ваше имя: ")


def w_menu():
    print("1)Свободный режим\n2)Бесконечная битва\n3)Выход")
    act_menu = int(input("Выберите действие: "))
    if act_menu == 1:
        locale.set(player_Home.l_type, player_Home.monsters)

user_print()
```

**data/gamedb.py**

```py
    import numpy as np
    from main import player_name
    class p_exp:
        name = player_name
        lvl = 0
        heals = 100+(lvl *10)
        enventory = np.array(["Зелья"])
        enventory_max = 10
```

**data/location.py**

```py
class locale:
    l_type = ""
    monsters = False
    def set(self, l_type, monsters):
        self.l_type= l_type
        self.monsters= monsters

class player_Home:
    l_type = "Дом игрока"
    monsters = False
    def set(self, l_type, monsters):
        self.l_type= l_type
        self.monsters= monsters
```

Comment: в папке есть файл __init__.py?

Comment: @КонстантинКомиссаров, `__init__.py` ;)

Comment: Согласен, но у меня произошло форматирование, потому что я не выделил это как код) В общем, да - `__init__.py`

Comment: Циклический импорт вроде бы

Comment: Вообще да, цикличный импорт, я проверил)

Comment: Еще, конечно, хорошим тоном считается называть классы с прописной буквы

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в циклическом импорте. Ну, можно сделать как

в **gamedb.py** убрать импорт имени:

```
import numpy as np
class p_exp:
    name = None #По умолчанию имени у персонажа нет
    lvl = 0
    heals = 100+(lvl *10)
    enventory = np.array(["Зелья"])
    enventory_max = 10
```

**main.py**

```
from data.location import locale
from data.location import player_Home
from data.gamedb import p_exp

player = p_exp() #Создаем экземпляр класса p_exp

def user_print():
    print("Информация о персонаже:")
    print("HP: {}".format(str(player.heals)))
    print("Инвентарь: {}".format(str(len(player.enventory))))


print('Добро пожаловать в игру "Подземелья"')

#когда пользователь ввел имя, то мы присвоили 
#новое значения атрибута нашему экземпляру класса:

player_name = input("Ваше имя: ")
player.name = player_name

def w_menu():
    print("1 - Свободный режим")
    print("2 - Бесконечная битва")
    print("3 - Выход")

    act_menu = int(input("Выберите действие: "))
```